# Why can't i instantiate ThreadPoolExecutor with BlockingQueue<Callable>; why only BlockingQueue<Runnable>?

Tags: java, java-5, threadpoolexecutor

My understanding is that callable was added in 1.5 and the runnable interface was kept as-is to prevent the world from ending.  Why can't I instantiate a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)`(core, max, tu, unit, new BlockingQueue<Callable>())` - why does the queue necessarily take runnable only?  Internally, if i were to submit, invokeAll, invokeAny callables, this should be fine right?  Also, would [`shutDownNow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdownNow%28%29) return a list of callables?

Comment: Because you can't add `Runnable`s to a queue of `Callable`s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can submit `Callables`, but they get wrapped internally as `Runnables` (actually `FutureTasks`, which implement `Runnable`). `shutDownNow()` is only going to return `Runnables`, just like it says on the tin.

If you want to get the list of `Callables` that haven't been run, you'll need to keep track of them yourself somehow (e.g., keep a list of them and make them responsible for removing themselves from the list when they're called.)

Answer (score 2):

As a more general answer, you can't influence the runtime behavior of a Java program by changing a type parameter. No `if` branch can be re-routed based on type parameters. If you ever find yourself in a situation where you wish to get a different behavior from an API, never look for the solution in the choice of type parameters.

In this particular case, a `Runnable` is a more generic type of object: it is a unit of work that the internals of the Executor can submit to a thread. For example, the `Runnable` can contain code which calls a `Callable` and saves its result somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  To understand better, you're suggesting that i use a runnable that wraps a callable (which will spit results somewhere else other than the submitter of the original runnable? how can i go about fetching this [there must be many ways depending on the environment] generally? and this ability to read results will determine what worked and not, which i suppose is more important, though, i'm still concerned about start of the execution at this point).

Comment: I think I've realized what is your confusion: you think that the passed-in queue is a part of Executor's public API, something which you'll be able to check for contents while the Executor is running, etc. But in fact you are passing in a building block of Executor's internals, and the reason the constructor accepts it is because the specifics of the queue's implementation influence important overall aspects of the Executor's behavior. You are *not* supposed to touch that queue in any way during normal Executor operation.

Answer (score 1):

It can't take both `BlockingQueue<Callable<T>>` and `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` due to type erasure; both overloads would have the same raw type `BlockingQueue`, and so would conflict.

I don't know what you would do with a list of `Callable`s submited to the executor, though. What would you do with their result? Where would it go?

It sounds like you want a [`Future<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). You can submit a collection of `Callable<T>`s using [`invokeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29), and you'll get back a collection of `Future<T>`s that you can get values from once they're available.

Comment: Well, I wanted to keep track of which callables didn't execute.  Say i submit/invokeAll/invokeAny a list of callables, and before I could iterate through all of the their future.get, or even before I could start iterating, the app is shutdown, and we issue a shutDownNow, can I expect a list of the ones that didn't even start running?  I suppose the answer is no, as outlined by @david-moles

Comment: @SaadShakil You could iterate through the `List<Future<T>>`s you got from `invokeAll` and check each for `isTerminate()`. Hard to give more specific advice without knowing the use case in more detail.